# Direction of propagation not being parallel of two light rays

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, geometric-optics, phase-diagram

[image]

Here we can see two scenarios where in the first one are two Ray's whose ditection of propagation are parallel and hence we can say that they are in phase which means they interfere constructively.

But in the second scenario we are finding two Ray's whose direction of propagation are not parallel. In this case,how can we determine whether the two of them are in phase or not? I do not understand this since there is no way to understand by seeing but in youngs double slit experiment,the light rays we have are just like these whose direction of propagation are not parallel and still we determine constructive and destructive interference when we can't say if they are in same phase or opposite phase. I do not get how the idea of phase being $\phi=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Delta x$ works where we can't say the phase difference by seeing. I know I have misunderstood concepts. So it will be really helpful if I am enlightened with the proper concepts.

Comment: You can “see” the phase difference at the position where the two waves overlap.

Comment: @FarcherFar it will be really helpful if you elaborate on the topic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in-phase just means that in a location that you chose the two waves will constructively interfere.

It does help that if you wish to set a relative phase value between your sources, that you chose a place where both sources are actually present simultaneously. As in your picture, its easy to find many places where your two light beams, propagating overlappingly and in the same direction, will show you their relative phases by the interference pattern...anywhere along their path.

Now, in the other case, only on that location where they overlap can you see the effects of their relative phase. If they are coherent and of the same frequency what you would see in their overlap region is something akin to a standing wave. You would see for example alternating bright and dark lines. In bright lines they are in phase, dark, out of phase. The period of the lines will be a function of their relative angle and their location is a function of their relative overall phase. As the location is relative to the relative phase, if their frequencies were not the same then the lines would be constantly moving towards a direction as the relative phase is constantly changing.

The example I gave is similar to that of the shear interferometer, where two beams have an extremely small angle of propagation between the two and they overlap. You can see some images in thorlabs website:
https://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2970

Bright lines they are in phase, dark, out of phase.